# db4o DotNet version with Xamarin MonoDroid and MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, db4o

Does anyone already used db4o OO database manager in a mobile project using Xamarin Monodroid and/or MonoTouch?

Is it even possible? (It seems that db4o uses Reflection.Emit(), which could be a problem)

Thanks for your comments on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on your app taking to a database directly, you might be better off to setup a web service (for security reasons you don't want your database accessible over a public ip address).

If you are going to work with a local database within the app to store data, use [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) and [sqlite-net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I want to know if db4o is available on those plateforms in order to avoid such ORM usage.

Comment: It is not available if there is no MonoTouch download on their website.  `Reflection.Emit()` is also not available.  They target .Net 3.5 and 4.0, but no mention of other targets.

Comment: I thought so. I will probably try some compilation with MONO in compilation symbol. It could be a good start. It seems that the `Emit()` part is not mandatory on basics feature. We'll see.

Comment: It is possible you may get it to work if you have the source to work with.  I've gotten several other fairly complicated open source libraries to work with MonoTouch (such as Ninject).  Use the source, Luke.